# Use my own domain on another website

Tags: dns

I'm using an application on a domain: **http://example.com**
I would like to access this application through my own domain: **http://mycompany.com**

I own **mycompany.com** domain but not **example.com**

When I go to **mycompany.com** I want to see **example.com**'s website.

Is it possible to use domain **mycompany.com** as if it was domain **example.com** transparently (without redirection) ?

Comment: Your best bet is to ask example.com

Comment: Maybe using transparent proxying. Do some investigation on nginx, haproxy etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a CNAME record on your own domain, but it probably won't work. The third party's server set up will probably not accept requests for your host name.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious reasons, this is not possible.

At a very rudimentary level, you can try using a full width and height iFrame on your **mycompany.com** site and load **example.com** into it. But this will provide very limited functionality and may not work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an app on another website, then chances are, you could use an iFrame...

If you are talking about replicating an entire website... Sceptical to why you would need to do this and would not advise it... The search engines would not like this duplication either.

Assuming this is legitimate, this could be done, but would involve some real effort... Too much effort! More effort than creating a site from scratch... unless the original site is quite complicated already...

You could bounce the users request to the orig (example.com) site and then provide a response to your user based on the response the orig website sends to you... but you have alot of work to do if you want it to look entirely like your site... How far do you need to go?

All the example.com links will need remapping to mycompany.com links... and then provide functionality to service those links from your

You may have trouble if example.com relys on Javascript for functionality too... This would need replicating

Also, YOU WILL NEED PERMISSION from example.com, don't do this without asking first!

It's possible, not very reliable and considering this method would only be employed for the most complicated original websites, this would take an army of people to get it right...

Short answer: Don't even bother!